# How to transition to a view controller with gesture swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, gesture, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a problem with implementing a button which should redirect my current view to another view when tapping on it.
I have a central view and I already implement the gestures on top, left and right to move to others views.

But on this central view I want to add a button that allows me to redirect towards my right screen without using gesture from right to left with my finger.

I added an IBOutlet action for this button, but I do not know what method to implement for switching back to my right screen (not the top or left screen).

If anyone can help me thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a segue in Interface Builder and give it an identifier. You can then perform this segue (what you call *"a transition"*) by calling

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: <String>, sender: self)
```

Of course you will need to replace `<String>` with your segue's identifier

---

- One can **create a segue** by control dragging from one view controller to another view controller
- One can **give a segue an identifier** by

  1. clicking on the just created segue (this is a line between the view cotrollers in the storyboard)
  2. opening the Attributes Inspector (press: <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> or click on: View > Utilities > Show Attributes Inspector)
  3. filling in the textfield next to the label "Identifier"

Comment: Thank but I already try this otpion with that but after, I don't have my animation that takes away the right to left (like with finger). The view is just pop over